# Adding Image to JPanel inside JFrame with multiple panels

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, jpanel

I added my image straight onto the jframe but then if i add another panel the image disappears,
i have tried to add image to a label and added this to a panel but this doesn't work either here is my code used to get my image:

here is my updated program:

```
    public class imgload extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private JButton b1;

        public imgload() {    
            makeframe();     
        }

        public void makeframe() {
         JFrame f = new JFrame();
         JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
         JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
         JLabel lb = new JLabel();
         b1 = new JButton("Confirm");
         b1.addActionListener(this);
         JTextArea q1 = new JTextArea();
         ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("sample.jpg");

         lb.setIcon(icon);
         q1.setLocation(10,10);
         q1.setSize(50,50);
         p2.add(q1);

         b1.setLocation(100,105);
         b1.setSize(80,30);
         p2.add(b1);

         f.add(p1.add(lb));
         // f.add(p2);
         f.setVisible(true);

         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.setSize(800,600);
         f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
         f.setResizable(false);
    }

        public ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {    
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b1) {
            System.exit(0);    
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new imgload();
    }
}
```

Comment: "but this doesn't work..." tells us little. Please take a little time to describe the details on what you're trying to achieve from a user's standpoint and then how your code fails.

Comment: Also you are mixing Swing with AWT components, and unless you have a very good reason to do this (you don't here) you should avoid this.

Comment: You're also directly adding a Component directly to a JLabel which makes no sense. Have you gone through the tutorials on using ImageIcons with JLabels? If not, I suggest you do so.

Comment: You're still trying to add a Component to a JLabel. Again, use an ImageIcon and set the JLabel' s icon with it. Again read the tutorials.

Comment: OK you're using icons and a JLabel, but you're still not using layout managers and haven't added the label to anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using layouts (BorderLayout, FlowLayout, GridLayout, GridBagLayout, etc) in Swing.  By default, most things have a BorderLayout, and when you use `add` with no arguments, it places the item in the center.  Subsequent calls just *replace* the item in the center.